# Code sees error, sends error message, but submits form data into session cart

Tags: php, forms, session-variables

The code between the asterisk lines checks for an empty field, and displays an error message above the form field.

Similar code that checks if an ID already exists in the cart is just below it. The difference between the two is that the code in question does not function as intended. It interprets an error, it sees an empty field was submitted, and triggers its error message.

The problem is that it also submits the empty string into the cart. I cannot figure out why.

I included all the code, if anyone wanted to test it. I hope someone sees what I cannot see. Thank you.

```
<?php
session_start();

// If no cart exists, create $_SESSION['cart'] array 
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

// Add item to array
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'add'){

/***************************************************/  
    // Check if input is empty / null
    if(empty($_POST['id'])){
        $error = '*Please enter an ID number.';
    }
/***************************************************/

    // Check if form data exists
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
    }

    // Check if ID already in cart
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){
        $error = '*Item already in cart.';
    }

    // Add new ID to array (hard-code some data for test file)
    $newitem = array(     
        'id' =>  $id,
        'part_number' => '369A7170-11',
        'quantity' => '1'
    );

    // Add new data to cart with ID as key    
    $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $newitem;  
}

 // Add item to array
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'update'){

    // Check if input is empty / null
    if(empty($_POST['id'])){
        $error = '*Please select item and quantity.';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    // Check if form data exists
    if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $quantity = (int)$_POST['quantity'];
    }

    $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'] = $quantity;
```

}

```
// Remove item from array
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'remove'){

    // Check if form data exists
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
    }

    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
}

// Empty cart
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'empty'){
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}

// Initialize $count variable; get item count
$count = '';
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])) $count = count($_SESSION['cart']);

// Display results
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $show_cart = var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);
    echo $show_cart;
}  

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Cart</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <h3>Cart Management</h3>
    <p style="color:#ff0000;"><?php if(isset($error)) echo htmlentities($error, ENT_QUOTES); ?></p>
    <p>Items in cart: <?php if(isset($count) && $count > 0)echo htmlentities($count, ENT_QUOTES); else echo 'none'; ?></p>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="id">&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id" placeholder="Enter ID number" autofocus>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="id">&nbsp;</label>
        <select name="id" id="id">
            <option value="">Select ID</option>
            <?php foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($item['id'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($item['id'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></option>            
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>     
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="remove">
        <input type="submit" value="Remove"> 
    </form>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="id">&nbsp;</label>
        <select name="id" id="id">
            <option value="">Select ID</option>
            <?php foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($item['id'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($item['id'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></option>            
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select><br>
        <label for="quantity">&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" size="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
        <input type="submit" value="Update quantity"> 
    </form>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="empty">
        <input onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to empty the cart?');" type="submit" value="Empty cart"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you set $error, and print it and nothing else. And this line (that I think this is the line that adds it to the cart) will be executed anyway:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $newitem;
```

You have to check the error before doing that. For example:

```
if(!isset($error))
    $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $newitem;
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmad for taking the time to review the code! Your solution works and is very succinct. Evan's solution also works but eliminates the error message. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In certain scenarios, you're adding an item with a key of `NULL`.  Here is the fix:

```
// Check if form data exists
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
} else {
    $id = null;
}

if ($id)
{
    // Check if ID already in cart
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){
        $error = '*Item already in cart.';
    } else {

       // Add new ID to array (hard-code some data for test file)
       $newitem = array(     
        'id' =>  $id,
        'part_number' => '369A7170-11',
        'quantity' => '1'
       );

       // Add new data to cart with ID as key    
       $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $newitem;
    }
}
```

The idea is that we do not want to add any entries to the cart if the id is empty.  Also, just to be safe, lets not redefine and add $newitem if it is already there.

Comment: Thanks Evan for taking the time to review this code and reply. Your solution works in stopping the submission of the empty string. Thank you! The error message connected to a submission of a blank field is now gone. Do you think that it's acceptable if a user clicks a submit button and nothing happens? Or do you think an error message should display? Thank you.

Comment: I think ideally they would see some feedback.  And ideally, that feedback would come on the client side before the form is ever submitted.  If all you want to do is make sure they don't submit an empty field, try adding the `required` attribute to the html element.  Most browsers will then automatically provide user feedback.

Comment: @JimB814 I missed something here.  You said "The error message connected to a submission of a blank field is now gone".  I did not post all of the code (as you can see).  I was only posting the part that should be replaced.  This starts at the comment `// Check if form data exists`.  The error message you're talking about occurs before my code block.  That is in the code you have between the asterisks, before my replacement code.

Comment: With the previous comment in mind, I actually think this answer is better than the accepted one.  This solution solves the OPs question completely, uses less memory than alternate answer, prevents the "variable not set" errors which will occur (because original uses `$id` even when it isn't set), and improves performance because the logic isn't asking redundant questions (as in, I already tested for and found an error, and now I am testing again if I found an error, which I already know).  Both answers do answer your question correctly, so in the end, as long as the issue is solved.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Two green check marks I think were in order here. Adding 'required' to the HTML was the easiest solution, but I prefer a PHP solution. I like the error message guiding the user versus nothing happening, even though arguably submitting an empty field doesn't merit any response. I agree that the 2nd error check works but doesn't feel like the best solution.